# VLC Playlist / plugin .lua - to load .srt from url

Tags: url, vlc, playlist, subtitle

I want to play subtitles from url.

I tried creating an .m3u playlist, but the subtitle doesn't load:

```
http://localhost:1111/1.srt
http://localhost:1111/1.mkv
```

Can VLC load a subtitle (url) from inside the playlist?

If not, I'm thinking of creating a .lua plugin for VLC to search the playlist for "http" access & ".srt" string.

If found I want to Download & use it.

I never created a VLC Plugin... Any help would be awesome...

Answer (score 3):

I did a work around `index.php`(list files in dir) + `javascript`(to download files):

1. download subtitle `CoolVideo.srt` (if subtitle exists)
2. generate & download `stream.m3u` (+ subtitle if exists)

stream.m3u + Subtitle content:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,STREAM: Cool Video Name
#EXTVLCOPT:sub-file=CoolVideo.srt
#EXTVLCOPT:subsdec-encoding=System Default
#EXTVLCOPT:subsdec-align=0
#EXTVLCOPT:freetype-rel-fontsize=16
#EXTVLCOPT:sub-fps=0
#EXTVLCOPT:sub-delay=0
http://localhost:1111/CoolVideo.mkv
```

stream.m3u (No Subtitle) content:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,STREAM: Cool Video Name
http://localhost:1111/CoolVideo.mkv
```

INFO stream.m3u:

- It's best to use `encodeURI("http://localhost:1111/CoolVideo.mkv");` for the video path just in case it contains empty spaces or other characters, otherwise VLC will not open the stream.
- Because `stream.m3u` is in the same folder as `CoolVideo.srt`, VLC will load the subtitle

---

3. Open the `stream.m3u` on PC, & enjoy almost any video format :)

---

BUGS: The subtitle does not auto load on Android